# iCloud preference pane loads indefinitely and prevents access to System Preferences

Tags: macos, icloud, system-settings

When I open System Preferences, it opens straight to the iCloud pane, which loads a spinner, states that it is loading, and then runs until I give up. While the spinner is up, I can't quit the app or load the pane, nor can I access any other preferences.

I don't have an iCloud account, and I'd like to quit the pane to make changes to my system. Is there any way to disable the pane or this behaviour?

Comment: Try deleting this 2 files: /Users/yourname/Library/Preferences /com.apple.systempreferences.plist and
/Users/YourUserName/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist. Then reboot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Launch Activity Monitor (in /Applications/Utilities) and look for a process named "com.apple.preferences.icloud.remoteservice".  Select it, click the little stop sign with the x inside it, and select "force Quit".

Comment: Re: answer by Eric S., this approach worked for me, thanks! I had to force stop "com.apple.iCloudHelper" to fix the issue.

Comment: When I see instructions to forcibly quit a process, I like to try the ordinary Quit option first.  In this case, that didn't work and I seemed to need to force it.